# Query filtering with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I execute a SQL query in Postgresql 9.2.24 that filters and shows the rows only when the last situation is 1. In example, show the row A,E,F. The PK is all columns.

```
Letter | Situation | Seq 
------------------------
A      | 1         | 1
B      | 1         | 1
B      | 7         | 2
C      | 1         | 1
C      | 3         | 2
D      | 1         | 1
D      | 7         | 2
E      | 1         | 1
F      | 1         | 1
F      | 7         | 2
F      | 1         | 3
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the *rows* use `first_value()` with a descending sort:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(situation) over (partition by letter order by seq desc) as last_situation
      from t 
     ) t
where last_situation = 1;
```

If you only want the letters, then a simple solution is `group by`:

```
select letter
from t
group by letter
having max(seq) = max(case when situation = 1 then seq end);
```

This is simple because it uses no subqueries.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=22ccb30001a657dfc3a8e2be3df4fc68) is a db<>fiddle.